# Combobox not loading with openlayers and silverlight in IE8 if mouse pointer is inside browser

Tags: silverlight, extjs, internet-explorer-8, openlayers

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/70687768/issue.png

In my solution I am using OpenLayers (for displaying Map) and Silverlight for Drag & Drop of Files (for File Upload functionality).
In this scenario, combobox component wont retrieves the data if my mouse pointer is inside browser, As soon as my pointer is moved out of browser (Or on Drag & Drop area, i.e., Silver Light control) the data wil be retrieved to the combobox.

Note: This case is catched only for IE8 browser with solverlight and open layers both.
If I check with Esri for Map instead of OpenLayer then it works fine.

I don't know it is issue with Open Layers or Silverlight control.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Check if you have overriding any events of ExtJS like Ext.Override of

```
onMouseMove : function (e) { }
```

Handle this event properly if you done above.

> 2.Same MoveMove event can be used in both the libraries(Openlayers and  ExtJS) there may be a Conflict in that case.